# in sql how to get the max of sum that is group by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT county, category_name, SUM(bottle_qty*(btl_price-state_btl_cost)) AS profit
FROM sales
GROUP BY county, category_name
ORDER BY profit DESC
```

I want profit for each county and what category_name is produces the most profit in that county.

So I just want the first row, 8th row and 11th row:

[image: So I just want the first row, 8th row and 11throw]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and what YOU mean by "profit".

Comment: i added the data and table and I justed one column for one county

Comment: Please add sample data as [formatted text](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) - **not images**. Include the expected results also as formatted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` to solve this greatest-n-per-group problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(county)
    county, 
    category_name,
    SUM(bottle_qty*(btl_price-state_btl_cost)) AS profit 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY county, category_name 
ORDER BY county, profit DESC
```

---

However this does not let you control the ordering of the rows in the resultset. In that case, use `row_number()` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        county, 
        category_name,
        SUM(bottle_qty*(btl_price-state_btl_cost)) AS profit 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY county 
            ORDER BY SUM(bottle_qty*(btl_price-state_btl_cost)) DESC
        ) rn
    FROM sales 
    GROUP BY county, category_name 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY profit
```

Comment: that work perfectly, is there any way I could order by profit bc when I try to order by profit only it says expressions must match initial order by

Comment: @Wangdu: not with `distinct on`, but there are alternatives. See my updated answer.